# Access Jenkins through Tomcat7 and Apache2

Tags: server, apache2, tomcat7

I am setting up a CI/CD server*h, hosted on a little box I have in the back of my house. e2/mods-e/Currently, I have a Jenkins instance running through Tomcat7 on port 8080, and a SonarQube instance running on port 9000.

What I would like to be able to do is access each of these via http://my.website.com/jenkins and http://my.website.com/sonarqube respectively, and block them from being accessed via the port (ie. http://my.website.com:9000/sonarqube)

Currently, I have a jenkins.conf located in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` linked to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/jenkins.conf` and the jk module enabled in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/jk.conf` and `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/jk.load`

This is the contents of my `jenkins.conf` (as suggested in [this](http://thetechnocratnotebook.blogspot.com/2012/05/installing-tomcat-7-and-apache2-with.html) post)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin zymus@localhost
    ServerName jenkins.mysite.net
    ServerAlias jenkins
    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass /jenkins http://localhost:8080/jenkins nocanon
    AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
</VirtualHost>
```

However, when navigating to http://my.site.com/jenkins, I get a 404 error. But, accessing it via http://my.site.com:8080/jenkins works.

What next steps could I take to achieve this?

UPDATE: I was able to visit the site by changing

```
ProxyPass /jenkins http://localhost:8080/jenkins nocanon
```

to

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/jenkins nocanon
```

But, I would still like not to be able to visit it via :8080. Or is this something I shouldn't be attempting?

EDIT: I managed to get everything setup. The main culprit was that I was defining the VirtualHost in each of the site config files, so sonar.conf and jenkins.conf both had the VirtualHost element. I removed that and both sites worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for your proxy server to be able to pass your request to and the response back from the jenkins server on 8080, it'll have to be available, at least to itself, at `jenkins_box:8080`.

*Restricting access:*

**From the wider internet**

If both the jenkins instance and the proxy server are running on the same machine (as in your case), all you need to do to prevent someone from outside your LAN (someone accessing `my.website.com` from the wider internet) is simply NOT forward port 8080 from your router to your server. **Forward just port 80.**

You could have nearly identical virtualhost blocks, one for sonarqube, set to the servername `sonarqube.mywebsite.com`, and another for jenkins, set to `jenkins.mywebsite.com`. Forward only port 80 to that machine, and bingo bango, from the internet, the only way to get to those services is by those subdomains.

**On your LAN**

Since the only device you want to allow to access `server:8080` is `server` itself, inside the virtualhost directives for sonarqube and jenkins, you can set the Allow and Deny settings.

For example:

`Order deny,allow
Allow from 127.0.0.1`

Would go inside each virtualhost block. You may also want to specify the server's IP address as an additional allowed IP (pretending your server's IP is 192.168.1.12):

`Allow from 127.0.0.1 192.168.1.12`

This is almost exactly the setup I have for several of my own services.